# How to modify this sed regular expression to replace extension of only a "."

Tags: regex, unix, replace, sed

I'm trying to get:

```
echo "penguin." | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".pippa"'/g'
```

to output:

```
penguin.pippa
```

How do I modify the code so that it can interpret the '.' properly?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

`sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".pippa"'/g'`

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "penguin."| sed 's/\.$/.pippa/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expression:

```
sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".pippa"'/g'
```

You are saying there has to be a alphanum character after the dot. `[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*` this says "one or more" of `[A-Za-z0-9]`. There is no alphanum after the dot, the string ends. So sed never applies the change. Remove that and you are all set:

```
echo "penguin." | sed 's/.[A-Za-z0-9]*$/.pippa/g'
```

Also, the quotes in the 2nd part of the sed expression don't do anything here.

Comment: This is actually part of a script I'm writing that needs to take this specific case into account along with other inputs, for example: 'a b' and 'penguin.dat' making 'penguin.a b'

So it needs to be written in terms of the "larger picture"

But your suggesstion works nicely. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "penguin." | sed 's/\./'".pippa"'/g'
```

or

```
echo "penguin." | sed 's/\.[A-Za-z0-9]*$/'".pippa"'/g'
```